# How to assign the highest value from the second column to the value in the first column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like this one and want to write for every A and every B in col1 the latest date from col2.

```
import pandas as pd
list = pd.DataFrame ({'col1':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 'col2':['2019-11-12', '2018-10-13', '2001-10-12', '2021-11-22', '2019-12-12']})

 col1     col2
0   A  2019-11-12
1   B  2018-10-13
2   A  2001-10-12
3   B  2021-11-22
4   A  2019-12-12
```

I want it to look like this

```
  col1     col2
0   A  2019-12-12
1   B  2021-11-22
2   A  2019-12-12
3   B  2021-11-22
4   A  2019-12-12
```

Comment: `df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('max')` Also, dont use `list` as a variable, since it can modify a built-in python method. Use something like `l` or `lst` instead.

Comment: The `['col2']` part isn't actually needed, but this is exactly how I would do it as well~

Comment: @BeRT2me I usually do that in case ppl have multiple columns in their actual data.